# Java. Initializing List in constructor

Tags: java

I have a problem of initializing List in constructor.

I am trying to assign parameters to variable "tr" and tr.getVertices() is a List.

```
SimpleTriangle tr = new SimpleTriangle(tr.getVertices(), tr.getColour(), tr.getThickness(), ShapeType.TRIANGLE);
trList.add(tr);
```

It higlights tr.getVertices() and says "Variable tr might not been initialized"

Where SimpleTriangle is a child class.

```
public SimpleTriangle(List<Point> vertices, Color colour, int thickness, ShapeType shapeType) {
super(vertices, colour, thickness, shapeType); }
```

and parent class has method

```
    public List<Point> getVertices() {
    return vertices;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on a variable you haven't initialized yet:

```
//              v--this variable        v--is not yet initialized here
SimpleTriangle tr = new SimpleTriangle(tr.getVertices(), tr.getColour(), tr.getThickness(), ShapeType.TRIANGLE);
```

You are trying to initialize a `SimpleTriangle` with it's own vertices, which doesn't make any sense. You'll have to pass some `List` of `Point`s to the constructor. The same is true for all other parameters of the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The error is correct, you cannot use a variable before it has been initialised.

You need to provide it real values, not ones which will only make sense in the future.

Note: Ruby does allow you to do what you suggest and could be considered a bug in the design of the language.

Comment: @PaulBoddington my favourite computer talk of all time https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat mentions it.

Answer (score 0):

tr is a local variable which you want to instantiate. You need to instantiate an object before using its methods. Its like you are asking null to get a process done. And in-fact you can not even call it null as local variables in java are not auto initialized.